# typescript undefined on the entire interface

Tags: javascript, typescript

How to declare the entire MyCustomObject interface can fallback to an empty object?

```
interface MyCustomObject {
   name: string, 
   age: number
}
```

Below case is safe, it has default property of name and age as fallback, but sometime if the `obj` is from other source like an api, it can be some other type like an empty {} or even an empty []

```
const obj: MyCustomObject = {
    name: "",
    age: 0
}
```

I tried this

```
interface MyCustomObject {
   name: string, 
   age: number
} | {}
```

it doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 3):

the most correct way is to create a union

```
type IUnionType = MyCustomObject | {};
```

other ways to handle this is to make each property optional

```
interface MyCustomObject {
   name?: string, 
   age?: number
}
```

Or create an optional object property where a union is defined in the original interface.

```
interface MyCustomObject2 {
    obj: MyCustomObject | {}
}
```

[examples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=10&ssc=1&pln=6&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8DCBXAzmAewFsB5AIwCsIExkBvAKGWZDiIgH4AuZfKUAOYAaZE2ZwBnHiGxEy0BgF8GDUJFiIUGHPmLkqNAEz0xzApR7a8hUpWq0APvWXKVCAiHzJzFS1mt6djTIALwmzCxsEDwARDFCpsgS0cgADEpuHl4%20hn46Nvr2oc6ZnrQ%20AMx5AbYGYMZhjBHeFiWuYOgADigAkgCqIMAeACpdKGFWurVFTnSKANyl2ZQALDz9gyNjxXMMQA)

Comment: The union type definition is the most correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have one interface having some member variables
suppose my interface name is IUser and variable name is iUser.
I have to make it undefine but I m getting error that we cannot make iUser = undefine
so I did something like this.

```
    let obj: any;
    this.iUser = obj;
    obj = undefined
```

and it works for me